# dyld: Library not loaded: on OSX

Tags: macos, ruby

I just got a new MacBook Pro, installed Catalina, and used the Migration Assistant to transfer my files over to the new machine. I changed the computer name and home folder for my account from `oldname` to `newname`.

I have a rails project that I was working on, and `rails s` is what I use to start the dev server. But on this new machine, I get this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/oldname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/libruby.2.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/newname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

How would I fix this? The binary exists in the `newname` directory, but the `oldname` directory is gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're afraid of rebuilding all of the project, and there's no support available for such cases, make a bare bone clone of the required folders in `/Users/oldname` which contains all the files required by the project.

**Warning**: This requires root password, and by default, `/Users/` only contains:

- All user accounts
- Shared
- Guest if enabled.

So I am not aware of the ramifications of the same.

Comment: the thing is that `oldname` folder straight up does not exist. `oldname` is the name of the system admin for my last macbook. `newname` is the name of the system admin for my new macbook.

Comment: make a new folder with the name of oldname, and copy required contents from newname